# PostgreSQL Math Function Error

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm getting an error from a deterministic PG function that seems dependent based on when I call it in a query.

The function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ircm(starting_money numeric, value numeric, days numeric)
RETURNS numeric
AS $$
BEGIN
-- Calculate effective interest rate, compounded monthly.
    RETURN 12*(pow((value/starting_money),(1./(12.*(days/365.)))) - 1);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If I call it in a simple SELECT statement, it works fine:

```
SELECT ircm(100.00,60.427500643787215,30)
Result: -4.79925436505569765596
```

However, when I run that exact same call from a different SELECT statement using a subquery:

```
SELECT
    ircm(100.00,m.v::numeric,30) AS result
FROM(
    SELECT 60.427500643787215 AS v
) m
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  a negative number raised to a non-integer power yields a complex result
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "ircm" line 6 at RETURN
```

Since the calls are logically equivalent, how can PG be returning an error for one call, but not the other? I've made sure there's only one definition of the function "ircm" in my database. I've tried dropping/adding it again to make sure PG isn't somehow caching a corrupted definition.

Comment: I've just tried on my machine (version 8.4) and the second one works for me and returns `-4.79925436505569765596`

Comment: What if you add the line `RAISE NOTICE 'value/starting_money %', value/starting_money;` in. This is the part that you're raising as a power and at least the presence of the print statement in the messages tab will assure you that the correct function is being used.

Comment: Same here: the example given works with 8.4.3 on Windows (through a JDBC query tool). So either this is a bug in your PostgreSQL version or you did not show us the full picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version and on which platform is your database running?

Have you tried rewriting the function in SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ircm(numeric, numeric, numeric)
RETURNS numeric AS $$
    select 12 * (pow(($2 / $1), (1. / (12.* ($3 / 365.)))) - 1);
$$ LANGUAGE sql immutable;
```

I'm running v8.4.4 on Solaris, Linux, and Mac OS X and achieve the same results from your plpgsql (and my SQL) version called directly, and from within the subquery.